# Option choices for Jasper Reports input controls don't appear

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

The available choice names for my input controls are not showing. I am not sure if it's the way a set the input controls. Also I would like to use a dropdown list instead of a checkbox. How can I correct these issues. Please see the current look in the image below:

[image]

Also, I tried using the  "Multi-select Query" and added the visible columns but got Null for the options.
Here is a screenshot.

[image]

I also used the following query which has two options which I added as the visible columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tran_type FROM prov.ATrans ORDER BY tran_type
```

In JasperReports Studio, I created a parameter of Class `java.util.Collection` with the "Default Value Expression" of

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Subscription", "Redemption"))
```

These are the values I expect to see but appear as null.

Comment: Please help, I've been at it for a while.

Comment: have you set Input Controls as Mandatory? And also, are you giving 'tran_type' in Value column and Visible Column?